# template class=default class doesnt do anything?

Tags: c++, templates

How do I make this work? Why is C++ letting me write `T=int` when it seems to be completely ignoring it?

```
template<class T=int>
class Foo {
public:
    T a;
};

int main() {
    Foo f; //error: missing template arguments before ‘f’
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo` is a template, you still need to write:

```
Foo<> f;
// ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write:

```
Foo<> f
```